# Formatar TextInput em Kivy/KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy

Tenho um TextInput que a função é adicionar um espaço entre o código de area e o número de telefone e um traço entre os últimos 4 números.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

KV = '''
TextInputNumber:
    hint_text: 'Phone number'
    focus: True
'''


class TextInputNumber(TextInput):
    def insert_text(self, substring, from_undo = False):
        if not substring.isnumeric():
            substring = ''
    
        complete_text = self.text + substring
    
        if len(complete_text) == 6:
            complete_text = list(self.text)
            complete_text[1] += ' '
        
            self.text = ''.join(complete_text)
        elif len(complete_text) == 8:
            complete_text = list(self.text)
            complete_text[6] += '-'
        
            self.text = ''.join(complete_text)
        elif len(complete_text) == 13:
            complete_text = list(self.text)
            complete_text[7] = ''
            complete_text[8] += '-'
        
            self.text = ''.join(complete_text)
        
        return super(TextInputNumber, self).insert_text(substring, from_undo = from_undo)


class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


MyApp().run()
```

Alguem pode me ajudar com uma funcao que ao apagar o ultimo numero o resultado esperado  seja, ex: 11 9123-4567.

Existe algo parecido com:

```
def keyboard_on_key_up(self, window, keycode):
    if keycode[1] == 'backspace':
        """ """
```

mas não consegui implementar, agradeço todo o tipo de ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Eu criei uma solução, para máscara de telefone (celular), também para CPF e CEP.
Da uma olhada no link abaixo, talvez sirva para você ou ajude a te inspirar em uma solução própria.
https://github.com/atsgrisolfi/mask-textfield

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).